# $f\cdot g=0 \implies f=0 $ or $g=0$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I know this is kind of an obvious thing to say:

Let $f,g \in \Bbb K[x]$, then
$$f\cdot g=0 \implies f=0 \text{ or } g=0$$

But to my surprise I couldn't prove it. What's a simple way to do this?

Comment: Write the polynomials (as) explicitly (as possible), then compute the product explicitly and conclude.

Comment: This is true as long as $\mathbb{K}$ is an integral domain.

Comment: What do we know about $\Bbb K$?

Comment: Yes, K was meant to be any field.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews OP is asking about function multiplication, not composition.

Comment: Ah, I assumed this was a harder problem than it was :p

Comment: Assuming $K$ is a field, what is the highest power (ie the degree) of their product?

Comment: Fix $g\neq 0$ and prove by induction on the degree of $f$ that $\deg (g\cdot f)=\deg g+\deg f$.

Comment: Essentially, all you have to do is show that if a ring $R$ has no (non-zero) zero-divisors, then $\deg(fg) = \deg(f) + \deg(g)$ for every pair of non-zero polynomials in $R[x]$.

Answer (score 6):

Equivalently, you can prove that $f \neq 0 \neq g \implies fg \neq 0$. To this end, assume that $f \neq 0 \neq g$, where $\deg f = m$ and $\deg g = n$. Then explain why the coefficient of $x^{m+n}$ is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

(Like) Simon says:
Assume neither is 0. And another way of concluding is that if neither poly.
is $0$, then $f.g= a_nb_m x^{n+m}+...$ i.e., the product will be a poly. of degree $m+n$, so that it can have at most $m+n$ zeros, unlike the $0$ polynomial, unless....

EDIT: But, like Mr Chonoles, said, this is true only if the coefficients are in an integral domain; you may have, e.g., $f =3x^2, g=2x^4 $ , in $\mathbb Z_6$, then $f.g=0$, even though neither is the $0$ polynomial.